# How do I get my program to loop if a character is entered instead of a number

Tags: python

I'm as new as it gets to programming. I have a question. Once the user has selected option 1-6, they are required to input the numbers they want to calculate, how do I stop the user from inputting a character instead of a number?

```
while menu: 
    usersChoice=raw_input("Please make your selection now:")
    if usersChoice=="1":
        print("You have selected AREA (SQUARE)")
        length=input("Input Length?")
        print"Area is:", length**2.0
    if usersChoice=="2":
        print("You have selected AREA (Rectangle)")
        length=input("Input Length?")
        width=input("Input Width?")
        print("Area is:", length*width)
        menu=False
```

Comment: `pi=3.17`?  Are you sure that's what you meant to write?

Comment: Building on what iCodez said, there is a Python module for math functions which includes the value of pi, the ability to square root, and so forth. If you're working on a calculator it may be of use. Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#module-math

Comment: @Jodi please note it's considered rude to vandalise your post after other's have bothered answering it... it makes those answers useless. Instead - either reduce the code so it's a minimal representation of the issue the answers are addressing, or if it has personal information you'd rather not disclosed, edit those out.

Comment: @Jodi If you wish the post to be disassociated from your account, or **really** need it to be removed, then flag your post (just under the tags on the question) - select other - and explain in as much detail as possible the reason you wish that action to be taken - a moderator will then evaluate your request.

Comment: I've already done so and need it removed due to school policy immediately

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Python have an `isdigit()` function.

You can use it to test:

```
"123".isdigit() #True

"a123".isdigit() #False
```

This only tests for positive integers, however. So:

```
"12.5".isdigit() #False
"-20".isdigit() #False
```

Comment: Well that is cool! Didn't know that, @MarkM answer is better.

Comment: Actually on second thought, it comes with a caveat: 

`"123.5".isdigit()`
#False

Comment: Ah, good to know. I was acutally just about to try this for some GPS cords stuff I'm working on, that would have problematic ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
def validate_is_number(number):
    try:
        float(number)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

validate_is_number(usersChoice)
```

You can the use the results of validate_is_number with an if statement to print back and ask for another response.

Answer (score 1):

you have some errors
 *from the first IF cond you are forget open and close bracet for print method
* the varable raw_input is not define into a programm !
* you write true loop forever print this things 
corect your error

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.isalpha()` to detect characters.

Ex:

```
usersChoice=raw_input("Please make your selection now:")
    if usersChoice.isalpha() == True:
         print("Sorry, your input must only be numerical. Please try again.")
         menu()
```